# Troubleshooting a 21 day window filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a job that runs daily that looks for accounts tagged with a specific status code.  The idea is that the accounts have remained with the same status tag for 21 days.  We recently discovered a flaw in the syntax that is allowing accounts that were tagged 21 days ago with the appropriate status and then tagged with a different status afterward to be selected in the result set.  I have attempted to correct the flaw, but the result is not 100% correct yet.  After much troubleshooting I am certain it is only the date filter in the query that is slightly off, and so I am only posting that portion of the query to remove distraction.

This is the original 21 day filter:

```
WHERE (([StatusHistory].[DateChanged] >= DATEADD(DAY, -20, { fn CURDATE() })  
AND [StatusHistory].[DateChanged] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(DAY, -20, { fn CURDATE() })))
```

I modified it to this:

```
WHERE (([StatusHistory].[DateChanged] >= DATEADD(DAY, -20, { fn CURDATE() })  
AND [StatusHistory].[DateChanged] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(DAY, -20, { fn CURDATE() })))
AND master.number NOT IN 
                (SELECT accountid FROM StatusHistory with (nolock)
                WHERE NewStatus NOT IN ('NSF','DCL') 
                AND DATEDIFF(d, datechanged, getdate()) < 21)
```

This modification gave me 99% of the correct result, but failed to pull one account that should have been included in the result set.  The only thing I can speculate is that the time of day is somehow coming into play.  I did run this query several times after the time of day the account was originally tagged with the correct status (in this case 3:38pm) and still it did not correctly pull.  I would really appreciate anyone's insight into how this can be tweaked to reflect the correct 21 day window at the time of execution.

Comment: Have you tried `CONVERT(date, [StatusHistory].[DateChanged]) = DATEADD(DAY, -20, { fn CURDATE() })`?

Comment: what if you consistently use either CURDATE() or GETDATE() instead of mixing them?   And consistently use either DATEADD, or DATEDIFF instead of mixing them?

Comment: Hi Nizam, I did try that, but no luck.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Hi Tab, that's a good point.  I didn't write the original query which used CURDATE(), and didn't think to modify that portion since it correctly identifies the 21st day.  I'll try it out both ways and see if either produces the correct result.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion from  Tab Alleman, I tested using either all getdate() or all curdate().  Using all curdate() proved to be the correct solution after a few weeks of daily testing.  Thanks for the assist Tab!

```
    WHERE (([StatusHistory].[DateChanged] >= DATEADD(DAY, -20, { fn 
    CURDATE() })  
    AND [StatusHistory].[DateChanged] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(DAY, -20, { 
    fn CURDATE() }))) 
    AND master.number NOT IN 
            (SELECT accountid FROM StatusHistory with (nolock)
            WHERE NewStatus NOT IN ('NSF','DCL') 
            AND DATEDIFF(d, datechanged, { fn CURDATE() }) < 21)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is over simplifying but wouldn't this work?

```
-- Group by statuses by accountid for the last 20 days and then count them
-- Report if more than one status
select accountid
from
(
    select  distinct accountid, NewStatus
    from StatusHistory
    where DateChanged >= DATEADD(day,-20,CAST(getdate() as DATE))
)q
group by accountid
having count(*) > 1
```

TEST: http://rextester.com/SYCXK56222

Comment: Hi Element.  That is a little oversimplified unfortunately.  Thank you though for the suggestion.